# ruby eval('\1') of gsub possible?

Tags: ruby, eval, gsub

I try to replace a sub-str by the content of a valiable where its name matches the sub-str by:

```
>> str = "Hello **name**"
=> "Hello **name**"
>> name = "John"
=> "John"

str.gsub(/\*\*(.*)\*\*/, eval('\1')) # => error!
```

the last line in the code above is a syntax error. and:

```
>> str.gsub(/\*\*(.*)\*\*/, '\1')
=> "Hello name"
>> str.gsub(/\*\*(.*)\*\*/, eval("name"))
=> "Hello John"
```

what I want is the result of:

```
str.gsub(/\*\*(.*)\*\*/, eval("name")) # => "Hello John"
```

any help will be appreciated. thx!

Comment: Not sure I totally understood your question here.. Could you please clarify. You wanna replace "Hello **name**" with "Hello John"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
str = "Hello **name**"
name = "John"
str.gsub(/\*\*(.*)\*\*/) { eval($1) }
```

The `gsub` method also accepts a block, which will be evaluated and the return value will be used as substitution. The special variables `$1`, `$2`, and so forth, are identical to using `\1` in a string.

A slightly better alternative than using `eval()` would be to use a `Hash` with replacement values:

```
str = "Hello **name**"
names = { "name" => "John" }
str.gsub(/\*\*(.*)\*\*/) { names[$1] }
```

Comment: Thank you! The Hash way is inspiring.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is not the answer to your question, but have you looked at [Liquid markup](http://www.liquidmarkup.org/)? It essentially accomplishes the same thing by using double-braces {{}}

```
@template = Liquid::Template.parse("hi {{name}}") # Parses and compiles the template
@template.render( 'name' => 'tobi' )              # => "hi tobi"
```